# NGX-Editor: Set cursor position

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the ngx editor and set the cursor position to an arbitrary location. It uses ProseMirror for this purpose.
ngx-editor docu: https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/en/editor/
ProseMirror docu: https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.Selection

```
import { Editor, NgxEditorComponent, NgxEditorService, toDoc } from 'ngx-editor';
editor!: Editor;

focusInput() {
this.editor.view.focus();

//here should i set the cursor position
}
```

I have tried all possible solutions on the internet, but none of them fit my purpose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.